# How do I access root node from event handler in Tree?

Tags: extjs, extjs4

How do I access my treepanel from an event handler inside of an Ext.tree.Panel ?

The following itemClick code does not work. I have tried going both **'up'** and **'down'**.

```
Ext.create('Ext.tree.Panel', {
    title: 'Example Tree',
    width: 200,
    height: 450,
    store: store,

    listeners: {
        itemclick: function(dv, record, item, index, e) {

            var me = this;
            var panel = me.up('treepanel');
            var rn = panel.getRootNode(); //panel undefined :(
        }
    }
}
```

However if I have a button in a toolbar it works fine :

```
dockedItems: [{
    xtype: 'toolbar',
    dock: 'bottom',
    items: [{
        text: 'Search',
        handler: function () {
            var me = this;
            var panel = me.up('treepanel');
            var rn = panel.getRootNode(); // :)
        }
    }]
}]
```

Both these examples are illustrated in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1cu3weoh/4/).

Comment: I think you can use me.getRootNode() as me(this) will refer to current component.

Answer (score 0):

This is how scope works in ExtJS(To be more specific, in Javascript). In the first example, 'this'(me) it self is treepanel. Try following

```
`listeners: {
        itemclick: function(dv, record, item, index, e) {

            //var me = this;
            //var panel = me.up('treepanel');
           var panel = this; //'this' is treepanel
            var rn = panel.getRootNode(); 
        }
    }`
```

Coming to the second example, if you observe the config pattern, it is a shortcut pattern to create a button inside the toolbar, hence 'this' becomes the button and you can get tree by component query.

Answer (score 0):

As you are inside the panel Bala's approach should work. If it doesn't try like below. The first parameter of the itemclick function is the view. You can get the panel from it.

```
listeners: {
    itemclick: function(dv, record, item, index, e) {
        var panel = dv.up('treepanel');
        var rn = panel.getRootNode(); 
    }
}
```